# Phpmyadmin error 500 when selecting database from web gui

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu, phpmyadmin, http-status-code-500

i'm facing with this lately after the update to Ubuntu 21.10. PHP version was upgraded to 8.0 but i was having problems with some joomla and wordpress sites. So i tried to switch back to PHP 7.4. After this get the following when i'm tryin to select a database
[image]

In apache2 error.log i get this message

```
Thu Nov 25 09:27:58.943302 2021] [php7:error] [pid 89321] [client 20.21.1.150:56534] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'static' (T_STATIC) in /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/Cache/CacheItem.php on line 67
```

my mysql version is 8.0.27

Is a privileges issue, a bug or something else?
Any help will valuable

Comment: I can see the 500 in the error message, but the rest is unreadable, and because it is an image I can't use a translator. Can you translate that error to English? Also, the line from the apache2 log seems unrelated to the red error message in PHPMyAdmin.

Comment: i tried to log in with English but the error gone! i will update if i get it again

Comment: When i log on using greek language the message is there, but when in English the message is not. I think its a bug

Comment: Could be a bug. Can you cope with English?

Comment: Which phpMyAdmin version are you using?

Comment: phpmyadmin     4:5.0.4+dfsg2-2ubuntu5